# Join the objects in a LINQ expression

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

How to Join the objects in a LINQ select in this sample (C# variants accepted as well):

```
Class Room
  Public Area As Integer
End Class

Class RoomPair
  One As Room
  Two As Room
End Class

Dim pairs as List(Of RoomPair) = mySource.GetRoomPairs()

' Select rooms with Area > 100 from my pairs '
Dim roomsAreaLargerThat100 = From p In pairs Select p.One, p.Two???

' roomsAreaLargerThat100 should be a IEnumerable or a List(Of Rooms) '
```

Comment: Why is this tagged c# when it is not related so c#?

Comment: read attentively the first proposition

Comment: Should `pairs` be defined as `List(Of RoomPair)`?

Comment: @MichaelMinton fixed, you are right...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Flatten the list, and then do a normal `where` condition:

```
pairs.SelectMany(p => new List<Room> {p.One, p.Two}).Where(r => r.Area > 100)
```

Comment: I was thinking along these lines but couldn't remember what method did it. Thanks for reminding me of SelectMany and getting me to read up the docs on it to understand properly what it does (docs here since I have the link to hand - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx).

Comment: could I also check if p.One or p.Two are not null?

Comment: @serhio You can add it to the `Where` condition, like this: `Where(r => r != null && r.Area > 100)`

Answer (score 1):

```
var bigRooms = Enumerable.SelectMany(pairs, x => new List<Room> {x.One, x.Two})
                         .Where(y => y != null && y.Area > 100);
```

If you wish to return a `List` you can simple call `.ToList()`.

Comment: That's not right, the type of x will be `RoomPair` not `Room`.

Comment: pairs is a `List<Pair>` so the above will not work (since x is a `Pair`, not a `Room`).

Comment: ) now is something similar to the dasblinkenlight's answer ) 
can I also check if  x.One and x.Two are not Nothing?

Comment: I've updated the answer to provide a null check on the rooms.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help you.

```
Dim roomsAreaLargerThat100 = From p In pairs 
                             Where p.One.Area > 100 || p.Two.Area > 100
                             Select p
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you need ins't a join, it's a *union*. Considering C# (because I might make some mistakes with VB.Net):

```
class Room
{
    public int Area;
}

class Pair
{
    public Room One;
    public Room Two;
}

// In some class...
public List<Pair> pairs = new List<Pair>();

// (...) in some method
// Retrieve the members "One" that are larger
var query_for_one = from p in pairs
                                where p.One.Area > 100
                                select p.One;

// Retrieve the members "Two" that are larger
var query_for_two = from p in pairs
                    where p.Two.Area > 100
                    select p.Two;

// Return the union of both queries:
var query = query_for_one.Union(query_for_two);
```

Of course, it might be better to write a method that would do it in a single iteration:

```
public IEnumerable<Room> GetRooms(int areaLargerThan, IEnumerable<Pair> pairs)
{
    foreach (var p in pairs)
    {
        if (p.One.Area > areaLargerThan) yield return p.One;
        if (p.Two.Area > areaLargerThan) yield return p.Two;
    }
}
```